# Remove comma from between JSON events

Tags: json, bash, sed

I was hoping to get Splunk to break up the content of the pages into events, but it's unable to. I'm trying to sed the comma that's in between the events out, but it's not going well. This is a portion of the json coming in

```
"last_updated":"2017-02-28T17:56:19Z"},{"id":588699,"name":null,...
```

and this is the sed line I'm trying

```
sed -e "s/},{/}+{/" -e "s/}[^}]*$/}/" secunia.txt | tr "+" "\n"
```

I've put it outside my for loop in the script that [barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42866822/6752652) helped with, but it's not pulling out the `,`. What am I missing?

Here is some of the data:

```
{"id":588699,"name":null,"status":{"id":2963,"name":"Handled"},"priority":{"id":2873,"name":"Urgent"},"queue":{"id":2144,"name":"Default"},"description":null,"assigned_to":{"id":4120,"username":"user4@company.com"},"asset_list":{"id":4777,"name":"Info Security Threat_Splunk"},"advisory":{"id":199003,"advisory_identifier":"SA74447","title":"Blue Coat Security Analytics Multiple Vulnerabilities","released":"2016-12-21T15:24:53Z","modified_date":"2016-12-21T15:24:53Z","criticality":2,"criticality_description":"Highly critical","solution_status":4,"solution_status_description":"Partial Fix","where":1,"where_description":"From remote","cvss_score":10.0,"cvss_vector":"(AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:C/I:C/A:C/E:U/RL:TF/RC:C)","type":0,"is_zero_day":false},"created":"2016-12-21T15:33:09Z","pretty_id":79,"custom_score":null,"last_updated":"2016-12-21T15:40:28Z"},{"id":584252,"name":null,"status":{"id":2963,"name":"Handled"},"priority":{"id":2873,"name":"Urgent"},"queue":{"id":2144,"name":"Default"},"description":null,"assigned_to":{"id":4118,"username":"user3@company.com"},"asset_list":{"id":4657,"name":"PSS Middleware Environment"},"advisory":{"id":195840,"advisory_identifier":"SA73221","title":"Oracle Solaris Multiple Third Party Components Multiple Vulnerabilities","released":"2016-10-19T14:20:02Z","modified_date":"2016-12-19T14:42:30Z","criticality":2,"criticality_description":"Highly critical","solution_status":2,"solution_status_description":"Vendor Patched","where":1,"where_description":"From remote","cvss_score":10.0,"cvss_vector":"(AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:C/I:C/A:C/E:U/RL:OF/RC:C)","type":0,"is_zero_day":false},"created":"2016-12-20T13:43:24Z","pretty_id":76,"custom_score":null,"last_updated":"2017-01-11T19:47:09Z"}
```

Comment: Better? I moved the text to the next line and have to type this apparently.

Comment: You should not be using `sed` to parse JSON in the first place. Use a proper parser, like `jq`.

Comment: I suggest to start with valid json code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command -

```
sed -e "s/,//g" -e "s/}{/}\n{/" -e "s/}[^}]*$/}/"  f
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the event separator works here, this assumes it does not occur elsewhere in the input though. For example:

```
sed 's/},{/}\n{/' secunia.txt | jq -s .
```

Or with portable `sed`:

```
sed 's/},{/}\
{/' secunia.txt | jq -s .
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 588699,
    "name": null,
    "status": {
      "id": 2963,
      "name": "Handled"
    },
    "priority": {
      "id": 2873,
      "name": "Urgent"
    },
    "queue": {
      "id": 2144,
      "name": "Default"
    },
    "description": null,
    "assigned_to": {
      "id": 4120,
      "username": "user4@company.com"
    },
    "asset_list": {
      "id": 4777,
      "name": "Info Security Threat_Splunk"
    },
    "advisory": {
      "id": 199003,
      "advisory_identifier": "SA74447",
      "title": "Blue Coat Security Analytics Multiple Vulnerabilities",
      "released": "2016-12-21T15:24:53Z",
      "modified_date": "2016-12-21T15:24:53Z",
      "criticality": 2,
      "criticality_description": "Highly critical",
      "solution_status": 4,
      "solution_status_description": "Partial Fix",
      "where": 1,
      "where_description": "From remote",
      "cvss_score": 10,
      "cvss_vector": "(AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:C/I:C/A:C/E:U/RL:TF/RC:C)",
      "type": 0,
      "is_zero_day": false
    },
    "created": "2016-12-21T15:33:09Z",
    "pretty_id": 79,
    "custom_score": null,
    "last_updated": "2016-12-21T15:40:28Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 584252,
    "name": null,
    "status": {
      "id": 2963,
      "name": "Handled"
    },
    "priority": {
      "id": 2873,
      "name": "Urgent"
    },
    "queue": {
      "id": 2144,
      "name": "Default"
    },
    "description": null,
    "assigned_to": {
      "id": 4118,
      "username": "user3@company.com"
    },
    "asset_list": {
      "id": 4657,
      "name": "PSS Middleware Environment"
    },
    "advisory": {
      "id": 195840,
      "advisory_identifier": "SA73221",
      "title": "Oracle Solaris Multiple Third Party Components Multiple Vulnerabilities",
      "released": "2016-10-19T14:20:02Z",
      "modified_date": "2016-12-19T14:42:30Z",
      "criticality": 2,
      "criticality_description": "Highly critical",
      "solution_status": 2,
      "solution_status_description": "Vendor Patched",
      "where": 1,
      "where_description": "From remote",
      "cvss_score": 10,
      "cvss_vector": "(AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:C/I:C/A:C/E:U/RL:OF/RC:C)",
      "type": 0,
      "is_zero_day": false
    },
    "created": "2016-12-20T13:43:24Z",
    "pretty_id": 76,
    "custom_score": null,
    "last_updated": "2017-01-11T19:47:09Z"
  }
]
```