# Detect the final page of a paginated cURL response in a Bash loop

Tags: json, bash, api, curl, jq

### Goal

Include all objects from a paginated REST API call in a single JSON file using cURL and Bash. This combined list will be fed into a Power BI report.

### Details

A request returns a maximum of 100 objects. There are 400+ objects total. The total grows over time. I don't want to maintain a script that includes something like `for set in 0 100 200 300 400 ; do` because it requires me to manually match the sets to the current number of objects. To save labor, I would like a script to auto-detect when the final page has been processed and then break.

To achieve my goal, the plan I have come up with so far is to extract each incremental set of 100 items into its own JSON file, then assemble them with `cat` and extract relevant JSON keys/values using JQ. The reason for Bash is that it is the only programming I know.

### Attempt

(Based on [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42866665/bash-scripting-curl-request-with-twist))

```
for ((i=0; ; i+=100)); do
    contents=$(curl -u "username:password" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://<url>/api/core/v3/places?count=100&startIndex=$i")
    echo "$contents" > $i.json
    if [[ $contents =~ 'list" : [ ]' ]]
    then break
    fi
done
```

#### Result

All pages export as expected except the first and last pages:

- The first `startIndex` should be `0` but the code makes the `startIndex` `100`. I have tried a number of variations with `i` but continue to fail.
- [edit: solved, thank you @weirdan] Neither `list":null` nor `next":null` end the loop. The script exports incremented JSON files indefinitely.~

### Reference

#### First page of returned paginated JSON

```
{
  "itemsPerPage" : 100,
  "links" : {
    "next" : "https://<url>/api/core/v3/places?sort=titleAsc&count=100&startIndex=0" <--- with my script, startIndex is erroneously 100
  },
  "list" : [ {
...
```

#### Intermediate pages

```
{
  "itemsPerPage" : 100,
  "links" : {
    "previous" : "https://<url>/api/core/v3/places?sort=titleAsc&count=100",
    "next" : "https://<url>/api/core/v3/places?sort=titleAsc&count=100&startIndex=200"
  },
  "list" : [ {
...
```

#### Final page

```
{
  "itemsPerPage" : 100,
  "links" : {
    "previous" : "https://<url>/api/core/v3/places?sort=titleAsc&count=100&startIndex=400"
  },
  "list" : [ {
...
```

#### Empty page

```
{
  "itemsPerPage" : 100,
  "list" : [ ],
  "startIndex" : 500
}
```

Thank you for any advice or ideas.

Comment: Well, looking at the pages examples `list` key never contain `null`, so that's one reason why the regexp would never match. You may also need to account for spaces around the colon (`:`).

Comment: You were exactly right @weirdan, thank you, as soon as I changed it to `'list" : [ ]'` it worked. I didn't understand what was happening there so thank you for explaining!

Comment: BTW, I would tend to suggest reaching for `jq` rather than a regex for the test. Using `-e`, you can tell it to set its exit status based on whether an expression is true, letting you use `if jq ...` just as one might otherwise use `if grep ...`.

Comment: `jq` is excellent suggestion indeed

Comment: As for the `$startIndex` part, I actually think that the first page *should* show 100 in it's `next` element. That element indicates the url where you can fetch *next* page of the result, and second page starts with record no 100 (given the 100 as a page size)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming my theory about `startIndex` holds water and implementing @CharlesDuffy's suggestion about `jq`, this becomes

```
for ((i=0; ; i+=100)); do
    contents=$(curl -u "username:password" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://<url>/api/core/v3/places?count=100&startIndex=$i")
    echo "$contents" > $i.json
    if jq -e '.list | length == 0' >/dev/null; then 
       break
    fi <<< "$contents"
done
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you weirdan and @CharlesDuffy